# simplifying an expression involving ratio of powers of a square root $(-a+\sqrt{a^{2}-1})$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have been trying to show that the expression below on the left hand simplifies to the one on the right hand. It seems that I am missing something obvious, but not sure what exactly. Any clues would be appreciated.

$$ \frac{(-a+\sqrt{a^{2}-1})^{4}-2(-a+\sqrt{a^{2}-1})^{2}+1}{2\sqrt{a^{2}-1} \ \ (-a+\sqrt{a^{2}-1})^{2}} = 2\sqrt{a^{2}-1} $$

Comment: The numerator is of the form $b^4-2b^2+1=(b^2-1)^2=(b-1)^2(b+1)^2$

Comment: I would just like to say, having the tags calculus and algebra-precalculus simultaneously is quite a contradiction!

Comment: looks related with inverse hyperbolic function. ${\rm arcosh\,} x = \ln (x + \sqrt{x^2 -1}) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u = -a + \sqrt{a^2-1}$ is a root of $x^2+2ax + 1=0$.
Hence,$$u^3+2au^2 = -u$$

Hence, $$\frac{u^4-2u^2+1}{2u^2(a+u)} = \frac{u^4-2u^2+1}{2u^3 +2au^2} = \frac{(u^2-1)^2}{u(u^2-1)} = u-\frac{1}{u}$$

$$u - \frac{1}{u} = -a + \sqrt{a^2-1} + \frac{1}{a-\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$
Rationalisation of the fraction in RHS yields,
$$u-\frac{1}{u} = -a + \sqrt{a^2-1} + \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2+1}}{(a + \sqrt{a^2-1})(a - \sqrt{a^2-1})} = 2\sqrt{a^2+1}$$

Comment: I have edited my answer. The final step involves using difference of squares identity.